# why is my `getClass().getResource("logs")` returns null?

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, resources

I have this code:

```
this.fileName = getClass().getResource("logs").toURI().toString();
```

which fails for null pointer exception because `getClass().getResource("logs")` returns `null`

what am I missing?

[image]

Comment: From the screenshot that looks like a folder, not a file. Not sure that makes sense for resources. Also note that this may not end up being a file system folder either, but a path inside of a JAR file. If you need actual files, better use the `Path` API instead of a classloader. What do you plan to do with `this.fileName`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a resource which is relative to the `LogUtils` class.

You could use `getClass().getResource("/logs")` or you could use `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("logs")`.

(In either case, I'm not 100% convinced it'll work when that's a folder rather than an actual resource...)